# How to make so every time a user clicks in a button, it safes 2 strings into an Excel sheet in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm currently building a website that simply presents to the user a string and a button, and what I intend to do is so when the user clicks the button, it then saves the string and another pre-determined string in an excel sheet. The idea is every time the user clicks the button, it saves the string on the street and writes it along with the excel sheet.
However, it's not working the way I intended and the second time the user presses the button, it gives me the following error on the `Workbook.Save();` function:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

This makes it so it only saves the first string but crashes when I try to write the second.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

To open the workbook and worksheet I use the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;
    TextBox1.Text = line[0];
    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Guilherme\source\repos\PAP\Dados.xlsx") == false)
    {
        oXL.Visible = false;

        oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
    }
    else
    {
        oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Guilherme\source\repos\PAP\Dados.xlsx"));
    }
}
```

and

```
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Sheets["Folha1"];
oSheet.Activate();

//Add table headers going cell by cell.

lastUsedRow = oSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;

oSheet.Cells[1, lastUsedRow] = TextBox1.Text;
oSheet.Cells[2, lastUsedRow] = "Boa Ideia";

oWB.Save();

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Guilherme\source\repos\PAP\Ideias.txt", line.Skip(1).ToArray());            
Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
oXL.Visible = true;
oXL.UserControl = true;
```

If there is any need for more code, just ask in the comments.

Comment: Excel ... really shouldn't usually be used as the backend to a website; if you're using the Office COM interop API, it isn't even supported or licensed for that scenario, IIRC; literally any real database would be preferable; is it *even slightly* possible to refactor this? (and that's before discussing issues like concurrency, app-pool recycling, server clusters, etc)

Comment: @MarcGravell I can use 3 formats that let me have columns. I was using excel because it's easy to convert but I can only use .csv, .tsv and .txt. What do you recommend?

Comment: what I'd recommend is: an actual database; but yes, you can use a flat file, in which case csv/tsv would probably be preferable to Excel at the minimum from a simplicity basis, but you'll need to think about concurrency and overlapped file access, perhaps using `Mutex` or similar, perhaps using a worker queue

Comment: @MarcGravell Well thanks for your help. I'll try that

Comment: "I was using excel because it's easy to convert" implies that you're okay with another interim data store as long as that store can ultimately be transformed into a flat text file. In that case, as @MarcGravell suggests, a database is preferable. Take a look at SQLite - it is free, requires no installation, can be created on the fly as a single file, and is very simple to interact with from C# code. When you need a flat file output, query it and export the content.

Comment: @AdamG Sqlite could work for limited scenarios, but will still run into some of the concurrency issues that Marc was mentioning earlier. It may not be important for this particular project, but it's hard to say for sure without knowing more about the context. An alternative might be something like [LiteDB](https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB), which will take care of the concurrency issues.

Comment: where is oWB declared? is it null? show your code

Comment: @mason Hello, I know it has been a while but I followed your advice and I'm grateful for your help. However, I am unable to convert the .db file to .csv. What should I do about that? My goal is to use that database as input for building an ML.net model, so it only accepts .csv, .txt, .tsv and SQL.

Comment: That's more opinion based and we try to stay away from that sort of question. I've barely used ML.Net, so I don't know what file type is best. The best advice I can give is: just implement something. You don't have to get the perfect implementation, you can learn from it wrong. So don't get hung up on .csv, .txt, .tsv or SQL. Just pick one, go implement it. There's plenty of ways to work with all of those from .NET.

Comment: @mason well my plan was to use .csv but when I try to convert the file, it gives an error and it doesn't work. When I tried seeing what was inside the file, I converted it to .txt and it was full of the letter y and in the final line, what I actually saved there.

Comment: If you're having trouble converting the file, that would be a separate question. You'd need to ask a new question and make sure you provide a [mcve].